# How can i add shipping at our own store location in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, stores

I'm very new to the **Magento 2**. Can anyone help me to overcome my problem?

- I need **`another new option`** is **`"pickup at our stores"`**.

So there will be no shipping charges for the customers. For this, should I install any **plugin** or **Magento 2** has inbuilt feature?    Please let me know about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own **custom module** in order to achieve that.
(Assuming you have registered your module already)
Follow the steps below to create Pick at store shipping method
**`EDIT`** : Added Custom Module registration

> registration.php
>   app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_CustomModule',
    __DIR__
);
```

> module.xml
>   app/code/Vendor/CustomModuel/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_CustomModule" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

> Step 1: Create config.xml file at app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <pickatStore>
                <active>1</active>
                <name>Pick At Store</name>
                <model>Vendor\CustomModule\Model\Carrier\Shipping</model>
                <price>0.00</price>
                <title>Pick at Store Shipping Method</title>
             </pickatStore>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

> Step 2: Create pick at store model at app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/Model/Carrier/Shipping.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\CustomModule\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;

class Shipping extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'pickatStore';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
     */
    protected $_rateResultFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
     */
    protected $_rateMethodFactory;

    /**
     * Shipping constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface          $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory  $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface                                    $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory                  $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param array                                                       $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }

    /**
     * get allowed methods
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return [$this->_code => $this->getConfigData('name')];
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    private function getShippingPrice()
    {
        $configPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');

        $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($configPrice);

        return $shippingPrice;
    }

    /**
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return bool|Result
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod($this->_code);
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        $amount = $this->getShippingPrice();

        $method->setPrice($amount);

        $result->append($method);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

> Step 3: Create configuration file at app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="carriers" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="320" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <group id="pickatStore" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Pick at Store</label>
                <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="0">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="name" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Method Name</label>
                </field>
                <field id="price" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Price</label>
                    <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Title</label>
                </field>
             </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Then **`run upgrade command`** to enable Pick at Store method.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade  
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f   
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Let me know please how should I run these commands and where should I run?
I have uploaded all these 3 files to the server.

Comment: are you on a live server? make sure you have registered your custom module already (module.xml and registration.php)